# View() received an invalid combination of arguments - got (tuple), but expected one of: * (torch.dtype dtype)

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, computer-vision, generative-adversarial-network

I’m trying to build a Generator for my GAN and this is what it looks like:

```
class Generator(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, latent_size, init_resolution=8, resolution=256, channels=3):
        super(Generator,self).__init__()
        #resolution = self.resolution
        #channels = self.channels

        self.cnn_torch = nn.Sequential()

        self.cnn_torch.add_module("Linear1", nn.Linear(latent_size, 1024, bias=False))
        self.cnn_torch.add_module("ReLu1", nn.ReLU(inplace=True))
        self.cnn_torch.add_module("Linear2", nn.Linear(1024, 128 * init_resolution * init_resolution, bias=False))
        self.cnn_torch.add_module("ReLu2", nn.ReLU(inplace=True))
        self.cnn_torch.add_module("reshape", Reshape((128, init_resolution, init_resolution)))

        crt_res = init_resolution

        #upsample
        while crt_res != resolution:
            self.cnn_torch.add_module("Upsample", nn.UpsamplingNearest2d(scale_factor=2))
            if crt_res < resolution/2:
                self.cnn_torch.add_module("Upsample Conv2d", nn.Conv2d(crt_res, 256, (5, 5), padding=1, bias=False))
                self.cnn_torch.add_module("Upsample ReLU", nn.ReLU(inplace=True))
            else:
                self.cnn_torch.add_module("Upsample Conv2d - else", nn.Conv2d(crt_res, 128, (5, 5), padding=1, bias=False))

            crt_res = crt_res * 2
            assert crt_res <= resolution,\
                  "Error: final resolution [{}] must equal i*2^n. Initial resolution i is [{}]. n must be a natural number.".format(resolution, init_resolution)

        self.cnn_torch.add_module("Conv2d final", nn.Conv2d(crt_res, channels, (2,2), padding=1, bias=False))
        self.cnn_torch.add_module("Tanh", nn.Tanh())
        print(self.cnn_torch)

    def forward(self, latent):
        fake_image_from_latent = self.cnn_torch(latent)      
        return fake_image_from_latent
```

But I’m getting the following error when simply trying to test it (with no images):

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-ccb426d28f8b> in <cell line: 14>()
     12 
     13 # Pass the latent vector through the generator
---> 14 fake_images = generator(latent_vector)
     15 
     16 # Inspect the generated fake images

5 frames
<ipython-input-14-8cb072a2d5c1> in forward(self, x)
      7 
      8     def forward(self, x):
----> 9         return x.view(self.shape)

TypeError: view() received an invalid combination of arguments - got (tuple), but expected one of:
 * (torch.dtype dtype)
      didn't match because some of the arguments have invalid types: (!tuple of (tuple,)!)
 * (tuple of ints size)
      didn't match because some of the arguments have invalid types: (!tuple of (tuple,)!)
```

I’m trying to test it this way to see if it outputs the correct tensor shape:

As you might see, it's not using any real images yet, only generating a random tensor in order to test out the final shape

```
# Instantiate the Generator
latent_size = 100
init_resolution = 8
resolution = 256
channels = 3

generator = Generator(latent_size, init_resolution, resolution, channels)

# Create a random input tensor that represents the latent vector
batch_size = 10
latent_vector = torch.randn(batch_size, latent_size)

# Pass the latent vector through the generator
fake_images = generator(latent_vector)

# Inspect the generated fake images
print(fake_images.shape)
```

Could anyone help, please? Thanks in advance.